# Python list help

Tags: python, list

simple Python question:

Example list: `A = [1,2,3,4,5]`

I need to generate another list B <strike>which is a shallow copy of list A</strike> such that B is a new list containing the same elements in the same order (so that I can substitute one of B's elements w/o affecting A). How can I do this?

---

clarification: I want to do something like

```
def some_func(A)
   B = {what do I do here to get a copy of A's elements?}
   B[0] = some_other_func(B[0])
   yet_another_func(B)
```

---

based on all your answers + the Python docs, a better way to do what I want is the following:

```
def some_func(A)
   B = [some_other_func(A[0])] + A[1:]
   yet_another_func(B)
```

thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You want a deep copy as JoshD mentioned. Really threw us off there!

Comment: Just added a clarification. I'm pretty sure I want shallow, not a deep copy.

Comment: @Jason S: your clarification doesn't help clarify what kind of copy you need. Look at the various answers below. They may reveal what you want.

Comment: hmm, then I'm off about what "shallow copy" means. I don't need the deep copy, but a straight "B=A" doesn't copy anything, it just assigns the same list to A and B. I want to copy all of the individual elements of A, but not any subelements.

Comment: @Jason S: OK. That would be a deep copy of the list, but a shallow copy of the elements in the list. `B = A[:]` will do just that. I believe `copy.deepcopy` will make deep copies of the elements, too.

Comment: OK, I've removed the use of "shallow copy" from my question, it's just confusing. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to make a copy of list A:

Use slice notation:

```
copy_of_A = A[:]
```

Use the list constructor:

```
copy_of_A = list(A)
```

Use the copy module:

```
from copy import copy
copy_of_A = copy(A)
```

As you requested these copies are all shallow copies. To learn about the difference between shallow copy and deep copy read the [documentation of the copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).

Comment: @Jason S, I guess I should have been more explicit with my link :) Also +1. nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

That would be a deep copy, not a shallow one.

Lists copy shallow by default. That's why there's a `deepcopy` command in the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).

`B = copy.deepcopy(A)`

Optionally, `B = A[:]` will do. But keep deepcopy in mind for future. More complex data types can benefit from it.

---

Added Info about copy:

A shallow copy:

```
b = [1,2]
a = b
b[0] = 11
print a  // [1,11]
```

A deep copy:

```
b = [1,2]
a = b[:]
b[0] = 11
print a  // [1,2]
```

But, furthermore:

```
>>> a = [[1,2]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b
[[1, 2]]
>>> a
[[1, 2]]
>>> a[0][0] = 11
>>> a
[[11, 2]]
>>> b
[[11, 2]]
>>>
```

So, the elements themselves are shallow copies in this case.

Comment: @Jason S, thanks. I learned something with this question. So +1 to you, too!

Answer (score 3):

`B=A[:]` suffices:

```
In [22]: A=[1,2]

In [23]: B=A[:]

In [24]: B[0]=100

In [25]: A
Out[25]: [1, 2]

In [26]: B
Out[26]: [100, 2]
```

`A[:]` uses slice notation to get the slice with all the elements of `A`.
Since slices of Python lists *always* return new lists, you get a copy of `A`.

Note that the elements inside B are identical to the elements inside A. 
If the elements are mutable, mutating them through B will affect A.

Comment: I think we all need to clarify when we mean a shallow copy of the list and a shallow copy of the elements in the list. When I hear shallow copy of a list, I think of `a=b`. What you've done, I would call a deep copy, even though the elements themselves are shallow copy, the _list_ is a deep copy.

Comment: @JoshD: I think you are right, I was misusing the term "shallow copy" as defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy#Shallow_copy

Comment: It's an awkward situation because both are happening. A is a deep copy of B, but A[0] is a shallow copy of B[0]. Your current answer is excellent and clears this up perfectly. +1

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
B = A[:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform that copy in the following way:

```
B = A[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=copy.copy(A)
B[0]=9999
print B[0]
print A[0]
```

`import copy` and use `copy.copy()` for copying.
see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) for reference.